# Designer equivalent of a dynamic event handler

Tags: c#, winforms, datagridview

So I have tab pages with datagridviews being dynamically created in code and to get the mouse up event on the tab I do this

Form1.Designer.cs

```c#
this.tabControl1.MouseUp += new System.Windows.Forms.MouseEventHandler(this.OnTabMouseUp);
```

For obvious reasons this wont quite work with the datagrids because they are dynamically created I have no direct access to them so to access the in code I do something of the sorts

Form1.cs

```c#
tabControl1.SelectedTab.Controls.OfType<DataGridView>().First();
```

I thought the equavalent to this in the designer would look like this 
Form1.Designer.cs

```c#
this.tabControl1.SelectedTab.Controls.OfType<DataGridView>().First().ColumnHeaderMouseClick += new DataGridViewCellMouseEventHandler(this.OnColumnHeaderMouseClick);
```

However this just crashes the designer

So what would be the equivalent code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So after a little more research and a lot of debugging and testing I found the solution

Since the designer does not do any complex searching algorithms at runtime theres no way for the designer to "search" for gridviews instead you can create a handler in the code when creating the gridview and attach it for each instance

```c#
//Get datagridview
DataGridView dgv = tabControl1.SelectedTab.Controls.OfType<DataGridView>().First();

//Create event handler
dgv.ColumnHeaderMouseClick += (s, e) => this.OnColumnHeaderMouseClick(s,e);

//Link datagridview to datasource
dgv.DataSource = ds.Tables[index.ToString()];
```